# How to add custom sort in Product GrqphQl query Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-graphql

I have a functionality where I have to display the bestseller products, so for this I am using Product query.
To full fill my requirement I am using one custom short attribute

```
products(
                search: "",
                sort: {trending: DESC},
                pageSize: ${params.limit ?? 12},
                currentPage: ${params.page}
            )
```

In Magento I have create a module which in which I am adding `ProductAttributeSortInput` in `etc/schema.graphql`

```
input ProductAttributeSortInput {
  trending: SortEnum! @doc(description: "Sort by trending products")
}
```

After running my code I am getting below error -
`Field "trending" is not defined by type ProductAttributeSortInput`

What I am doing wrong in this?

Or if you can share any sample using which I can get the bestseller products from Magento 2 using graphQl query.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: enable product attribute sorting in magento backend.

Comment: @Pramod `trending` is custom attribute